# Should I store never changing (bootstrapped) data in the store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, flux

I have some state in my application that is coming from the server and not going to change (during the lifetime of user session). This state is bootstrapped in HTML.

Should I incorporate it in a reducer as a part of the store? 
`const bootstrappedData = (state, action) => state`

Or should I expose some global helper like `bootstrappedData.get('key')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Funny, I hit this same decision just yesterday regarding data in my own store. And I reached the conclusion that we should only be storing **stateful** data in the Redux store, that is, data that is capable of maintaining state, or data that is subject to change. Static data by definition does not have state, and therefore does not need to be tracked as such.

As a result, I typically have a `/common/app-const.js` file where I store these types of static objects. For instance, I store the `DEFAULT_STATE` of Redux, here, but also some other objects which are not subject to change (and are therefore not tracked in Redux).

Now let's say I actually want to allow the end-user to manipulate `numRows` and `numCols` in the UI, well at that point I would surely need to put these in the Redux store, but not now, since they are just static constants!

**/common/app-const.js**

```
export const DEFAULT_STATE = {
    model: {},
    timer: {
        isRunning: false,
        ticks: 0
    }
};

export const GRID_DATA = {
    numRows: 50,
    numCols: 75,
};
```

And whenever I need this static data, it's as easy as an import:

```
import { GRID_DATA } from '../common/app-const';
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly related to this question is asynchronous (not bootstrapped) but static data,

For that, there are tradeoffs to storing the data in the Store vs. outside the Store.

---

**Inside the Store**

**PROS**

- easy to see and debug data without using `console.log`
- querying data is synchronous via selectors

**CONS**

- conceptual inaccurate, since the static data by definition isn't stateful, whereas the store is meant to hold state

---

**Outside the Store**

**PROS**

- conceptually accurate (based on [this reasoning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35875960/2419669))

**CONS**

- since the data is async, you'll have to export async data access APIs (vs. synchronous selectors)
- async data leads to stateful Components (fetching the data in lifecycle hooks and setting the data as state, e.g.)

I've done the former approach in a large production app, and would much rather have done the latter, in retrospect.